# How to manipulate the input using dataweave to get the desired output?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

**Input Json**
{
"Name": {
"displayValue": null,
"value": "EQ-10186735"
},
"SP_Altitude__c": {
"displayValue": null,
"value": "ALT001"
},
"SP_Batch_Number__c": {
"displayValue": null,
"value": "Batch_number_001"
},
"SP_Classification__c": {
"displayValue": null,
"value": "Products"
},
"SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": {
"displayValue": null,
"value": "Eqpartner__1"
},
"SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": {
"displayValue": "Eqpartner__1"
"value": ""
},
"SP_Delivery_Date__c": {
"displayValue": "02.09.2016",
"value": "2016-09-02"
},
"SP_Delivery_Note__c": {
"displayValue": null,
"value": "82849654"
},
"SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": {
"displayValue": null,
"value": "2019-03-02"
},
"SP_Product_Number__c": {
"displayValue": null,
"value": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
}
}

**Output**
[
"Name": "EQ-10186735",
"SP_Altitude__c": "ALT001",
"SP_Batch_Number__c": "Batch_number_001",
"SP_Classification__c": "Products",
"SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": "Eqpartner__1",
"SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": "Eqpartner__1",
"SP_Delivery_Date__c": "2016-09-02",
"SP_Delivery_Note__c": "82849654",
"SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": "2019-03-02"
"SP_Product_Number__c": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the request and desired response, the value for a key are one level deep. I used online dw [playground](https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/) passing your input request and here is the code to get your desired output.

```
   %dw 2.0 output application/json
  payload mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {(key):value.value} )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The given output is an array, but it has key/value pairs. So i assume the output type is Object.

If that's the case, you can use mapObject.

```
payload mapObject ((item, key) -> {
    (key): item.value
} )
```

Output is

```
{
  "Name": "EQ-10186735",
  "SP_Altitude__c": "ALT001",
  "SP_Batch_Number__c": "Batch_number_001",
  "SP_Classification__c": "Products",
  "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": "Eqpartner__1",
  "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": "",
  "SP_Delivery_Date__c": "2016-09-02",
  "SP_Delivery_Note__c": "82849654",
  "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": "2019-03-02",
  "SP_Product_Number__c": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
}
```

You can also use pluck to get array of objects like below

```
payload pluck ((item, key) -> {
    (key): item.value
})
```

Output: -

```
[
  {
    "Name": "EQ-10186735"
  },
  {
    "SP_Altitude__c": "ALT001"
  },
  {
    "SP_Batch_Number__c": "Batch_number_001"
  },
  {
    "SP_Classification__c": "Products"
  },
  {
    "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": "Eqpartner__1"
  },
  {
    "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": ""
  },
  {
    "SP_Delivery_Date__c": "2016-09-02"
  },
  {
    "SP_Delivery_Note__c": "82849654"
  },
  {
    "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": "2019-03-02"
  },
  {
    "SP_Product_Number__c": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: I have a further use case related to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69916630/from-the-given-json-i-want-to-get-the-desired-output-how-to-do-it-using-datawe

can you please look at it too?