# From the given json, I want to get the desired output, How to do it using dataweave?

Tags: mule, dataweave

**Input**

```json
{
    "editable": true,
    "sections": [
            {
                "title": "Identification",
                "Content": [
                    {
                        "name": "Classification",
                        "apiname": "SP_Classification__c",
                        "text": {
                            "Name": "EQ-10186735",
                            "SP_Altitude__c": "A001",
                            "SP_Batch_Number__c": "B001",
                            "SP_Classification__c": "Products",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": "E001",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": "E002",
                            "SP_Delivery_Date__c": "2016-09-02",
                            "SP_Delivery_Note__c": "82849654",
                            "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": "End001",
                            "SP_Product_Number__c": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
                        },
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Product Number",
                        "apiname": "SP_Product_Number__c",
                        "text": {
                            "Name": "EQ-10186735",
                            "SP_Altitude__c": "A001",
                            "SP_Batch_Number__c": "B001",
                            "SP_Classification__c": "Products",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": "E001",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": "E002",
                            "SP_Delivery_Date__c": "2016-09-02",
                            "SP_Delivery_Note__c": "82849654",
                            "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": "End001",
                            "SP_Product_Number__c": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
                        },
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Current Equipment Partner",
                        "apiname": "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c",
                        "text": {
                            "Name": "EQ-10186735",
                            "SP_Altitude__c": "A001",
                            "SP_Batch_Number__c": "B001",
                            "SP_Classification__c": "Products",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": "E001",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": "E002",
                            "SP_Delivery_Date__c": "2016-09-02",
                            "SP_Delivery_Note__c": "82849654",
                            "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": "End001",
                            "SP_Product_Number__c": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
                        },
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "End of Commissioning",
                        "apiname": "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c",
                        "text": {
                            "Name": "EQ-10186735",
                            "SP_Altitude__c": "A001",
                            "SP_Batch_Number__c": "B001",
                            "SP_Classification__c": "Products",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": "E001",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": "E002",
                            "SP_Delivery_Date__c": "2016-09-02",
                            "SP_Delivery_Note__c": "82849654",
                            "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": "End001",
                            "SP_Product_Number__c": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
                        },
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "Position And Contact",
                "Content": [
                    {
                        "name": "Batch Number",
                        "apiname": "SP_Batch_Number__c",
                        "text": {
                            "Name": "EQ-10186735",
                            "SP_Altitude__c": "A001",
                            "SP_Batch_Number__c": "B001",
                            "SP_Classification__c": "Products",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": "E001",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": "E002",
                            "SP_Delivery_Date__c": "2016-09-02",
                            "SP_Delivery_Note__c": "82849654",
                            "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": "End001",
                            "SP_Product_Number__c": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
                        },
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Altitude",
                        "apiname": "SP_Altitude__c",
                        "text": {
                            "Name": "EQ-10186735",
                            "SP_Altitude__c": "A001",
                            "SP_Batch_Number__c": "B001",
                            "SP_Classification__c": "Products",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c": "E001",
                            "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__r": "E002",
                            "SP_Delivery_Date__c": "2016-09-02",
                            "SP_Delivery_Note__c": "82849654",
                            "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c": "End001",
                            "SP_Product_Number__c": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z"
                        },
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
    ]
}
```

**Output**

```json
{
    "editable": true,
    "sections": [
            {
                "title": "Identification",
                "Content": [
                    {
                        "name": "Classification",
                        "apiname": "SP_Classification__c",
                        "text": "Products"
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Product Number",
                        "apiname": "SP_Product_Number__c",
                        "text": "1MV4567-6BJ60-4BD0-Z",
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Current Equipment Partner",
                        "apiname": "SP_Current_Equipment_Partner__c",
                        "text": "E001,
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "End of Commissioning",
                        "apiname": "SP_End_of_Commissioning__c",
                        "text": "End001",
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "Position And Contact",
                "Content": [
                    {
                        "name": "Batch Number",
                        "apiname": "SP_Batch_Number__c",
                        "text": "B001,
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Altitude",
                        "apiname": "SP_Altitude__c",
                        "text": "A001",
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to need to map every attribute as it is except for the `text` attribute inside Content elements. Those can be filtered with filterObject()

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    editable: payload.editable,
    sections: payload.sections map 
        {
            title: $.title,
            Content: $.Content map 
                ($ mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
                        (key):  if (key as String != "text") value 
                             else value[$.apiname]
                    )
                )
        }
}
```

Comment: No No, i do need the "text" field as well, based on the apiName field.

Comment: currently if you look closely, the text field is having all the values based on the key value pairs. I want the value of the text to be of that of the corresponding apiName.

eg: {
                        "name": "Classification",
                        "apiname": "SP_Classification__c",
                        "text": "Products"
                        "url": "",
                        "info": ""
                    }

Comment: Sorry I missed it the first time. I fixed it now.

Comment: It's not working for me, gives me this error : You called the function 'Dynamic Selector' with these arguments: 
  1: Object ({Name: "EQ-10186735",SP_Altitude__c: "A001",SP_Batch_Number__c: "B001",SP_Cla...)
  2: Null (null)

  else value[$.apiName]
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main::main (line: 12, column: 35)

Comment: I'm not having that issue with the input provided in the question.